# Why were Slughorn's memories "congealed"?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, when Dumbledore is about to show Slughorn's memories to Harry, it is mentioned that

> Harry noticed that the contents proved difficult to empty into the Pensieve, as though they had congealed slightly; did memories go off?

Is it ever explained why the memories had this congealed appearance?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The unexpected consistency is presumably foreshadowing the fact that Slughorn has gone back and tried to edit his memories to cover up the mistakes he had made in his interactions with Riddle.  The memories don't flow the way they are supposed to because other stuff that does not belong has been mixed in with them.

Comment: I had a similar thought, but more along the lines of that the "congealed" state of them was because he provided them reluctantly, which influenced their texture. Tomato, tomato, as they say.